# Nunit Assertion for an empty intersection between collection

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, nunit

I've looked all around, and can't quite figure this one out, and my multitude of trial and error attempts have all been useless.

I have a list of user names (we'll call 'original list') one object is returning
I have a list of user names (we'll call 'filtration list') another object is returning

I am testing a method that returns all of the items from the original list not in the filtration list.

Ideally what I want is something like

```
Assert.That(returnedList, Has.No.Members.In(filtrationList))
```

So far the only thing I can do is iterate over the filtrationList and do

```
Assert.That(returnedList, Has.None.EqualTo(filteredUser))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nunit you can create any custom constraint.
If you want to verify two collections for intersection, you can create something like this:

```
public class Intersects : CollectionConstraint
{
    private IEnumerable _collection2;

    public Intersects(IEnumerable collection2)
        : base(collection2)
    {
        _collection2 = collection2;
    }

    public static Intersects With(IEnumerable arg)
    {
        return new Intersects(arg);
    }

    protected override bool doMatch(IEnumerable collection)
    {
        foreach (object value in collection)
        {
            foreach (object value2 in _collection2)
                if (value.Equals(value2))
                    return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override void WriteDescriptionTo(MessageWriter writer)
    {
        //You can put here something more meaningful like items which should not be in verified collection.
        writer.Write("intersecting collections");
    }
}
```

usage is pretty simple:

```
string[] returnedList = new string[] { "Martin", "Kent", "Jack"};
List<string> filteredUsers = new List<string>();
filteredUsers.Add("Jack");
filteredUsers.Add("Bob");
Assert.That(returnedList, Intersects.With(filteredUsers));
```

Comment: I created a class "IsDisjointSet" with the doMatch logic flipped and a fluent method 
public static IsDisjointSet ComparedTo(IEnumerable arg)

with